# Is WIF a must to integrate with ADFS 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

I'm quite new to ADFS stuff. Would like to know whether WIF is a must in order to use ADFS 2.0 for SSO authentication?

Currently I'm trying to integrate a .NET web application (v.4.5.2) with ADFS 2.0. Most of the article I found online will require WIF to trust incoming token from Federated Server.

Comment: Interesting as most of modern articles should refer to OWIN which also supports ws-fed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADFS options are:

**ADFS 3.0 and down:**

- WS-Fed via WIF or OWIN
- SAML via OWIN

**ADFS 4.0:**

- WS-Fed via WIF or OWIN
- SAML via OWIN
- OpenID Connect via OWIN

So, no you don't have to use WIF.

Refer: [Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation) and [Kentor.AuthServices.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Owin/).

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 4.5 WIF is completely integrated with the framework. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) for more details.